# Generating username from Fullname field and adding 8 char string with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to generate unique username for every user during registration based on his/her name, user can change it later.

## my models.py :

```
full_name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) //I want this to be auto generated
```

> Example : full_name: abc.mc username: abc.mc #fdg415

I am using drf to get these data and while doing so I want to fill the username field

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=HNUsers.objects.all())]
    )
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=HNUsers.objects.all())]
    )

    required_formats = ['%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d']
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y', 'iso-8601'])
    class Meta:
        model = HNUsers
        fields = [
            'full_name',
       
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
       
        return HNUsers.objects.create(full_name=validated_data['full_name'])
```

any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it in your validated_data:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    full_name = validated_data.get('full_name')
    validated_data['username'] = fullname + '#dcf' // whatever logic you want to use here
    return super(RegisterSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    # or 
    # return HNUsers.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: hi, I tried but it comes with username = null and fullname = null in response

Comment: can you debug and see if you are getting full_name in get()?

Comment: @Mitesh  Edited my response, use serializer to create().

Comment: It works like a charm .. thanks .. if you dont mind can you please explain why it worked my one didnt? Again thanks a lot

Comment: Glad i could help!. You mean my first post right? i just missed ** in create ie. it should have been HNUsers.objects.create(**validated_data) since validated_data is a dict. You can use either of these methods to save, i've always used super() since i began so i wronte that subconsciously :P  I'll add that too in the response

Comment: One more thing if I want to have the username without any spaces and replaced by '.' for example : fullname : abcd md and username will be username: abcd.md #ds3f25s4f. what do i have to do?

Comment: @Mitesh  you mean something like this?  username = fullname.replace(' ', '.') + ' #ds3f25s4f'